# using com.sun.media.sound.javasoundaudioclip classes in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I try to use JavaSoundAudioClip classes in Ubuntu however It could not be found in. How can I get it to Ubuntu? Isn't it a default library for Java?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any packages prefixed com.sun.* because they are Sun's internal packages and are not intended for external use, as they are subject to change without warning:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

The public API, that is supported for external use is *javax.sound.**

Documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html

You can also find a lot of useful packages in [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/).